# popup from asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

how can i show an popup coming from a controller after my task has finished? something like to notice the user it has been finished?

Answer (score 4):

You have to return an `ActionResult` from the controller action that can be rendered by the browser.  That's usually either a whole page, or a partial page or JSON data returned to an Ajax call.  The javascript in the page can then display the result returned.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this as following:

step 1- create a partial view name "_Empty.cshtml"

then, in that view you can send message to end user based on your controller condition.

and in the controller write this two lines:

ViewData["AlertMessage"] = AlertMessage.NoClient;
   return PartialView("_Empty");

here the user not select any client, so i redirect user to empty partial view and tell user that please select client then proceed to another opration.